# How do I set up a software raid when using NVMe drives?

Tags: linux, software-raid, nvme

I'm currently trying to set up a software RAID1 on a machine that uses Ubuntu 20.04 with UEFI as the drives are running over NVMe.

I've tried to just manually copy the EFI partition over to the second drive with `dd` and then use `efibootmgr` to add it to the boot order. This works for normal drives, but I get an error when using NVMe drives:

```
mdadm: error opening /dev/md?*: No such file or directory
done.
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- missing modules (car /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=94944b6c.... doesn't not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

Any idea why?

After days of searching, I've yet to find an answer.